# How to get the full CPU usage on Ray cluster, while executing RLlib algorithms?

Tags: cluster-computing, ray

I am trying to run rllib algorithms on ray cluster. I get the following message as,
"Memory usage on this node: 20.8/64.4 GB"

How shall i make it use the memory fully? How to cross check whether the GPU or CPU utilization is above 90%?

Kindly help....

Comment: You can usually check CPU utilization with `top` and GPU utilization with `nvidia-smi`. You probably don't want memory utilization to be 100% because then things will run out of memory.

Answer (score 0):

You can usually check CPU utilization with `top` and GPU utilization with `nvidia-smi`. You probably don't want memory utilization to be 100% because then things will run out of memory.

Comment: As i am running the algorithms on Ray cluster. How do i check with "top" command?

Comment: Oh I see, you can ssh to each machine and run `top`. You can also view the information in the dashboard, which was merged in https://github.com/ray-project/ray/pull/4066. However that has not been released yet, but will be in the next release.